# Incorrect no_results page returned for simple search

Tags: search

This site has been updated from 1.7.1 to 2.6.1, there are no known issues other than this one at present.

The problem is that the search no_results page is from the old site (design, css, imagery etc), however, the template that is in both the db and the file system (saving templates as files) is a new one.

In the simple search form params we have

```
{exp:search:simple_form
  channel = 'blog'
  status = 'open'
  search_in = 'everywhere'
  no_result_page = 'search/no-results'
  results = '100'
}
```

The url that a no results search displays is

```
/search/no-results/27e28542d78e8e6c2cafef090a2007b5/
```

the hash (segment_3 varies for different unfound terms)

and in both the db and the templates directory we have a search group,

```
search.group
    index.html (empty)
    no-results.html
    results.html
```

The content of the no-results.html is the new code, both in the db and the files.

A 'successful' search uses the results.html template above it's just the no-results that are coming out on the 'old' template.

In addition we have tested this

1. Logged in and logged out
2. After clearing cookies
3. After clearing all site caches
4. After synching templates and checking the content in the control panel, database and file system.
5. It happens on a variety of machines (eliminating browser caching)
6. There are no rewrite rules that match

We have no idea where the system is finding this template from. Any ideas?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What happens if you try to open search/no-results?

Comment: Is template revisions on? If so, does turning it off help?

Answer (score 1):

This is a silly mistake on my part.

What I hadn't noticed was that there was a stray search opening tag further up the template that should have been removed.

This was in fact throwing an error, and the template that was being displayed was the error template from

```
Design -> Message Pages -> User Messages
```

Once I tracked down the stray tag it was all working as it should. The reason it looked like the old site was that they had hardcoded all of the css into the head of the template.